# Minimum packages required to distribute balls

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

We have R red, G green, and B blue balls. We want to divide them into as few packages as possible. Each package must contain 1, 2, or 3 balls. Additionally, each package must be either a "normal set" (all balls in the package have the same color), or a "variety set" (no two balls have the same color). What will be the smallest possible number of packages needed.

EXAMPLE : LET R=4 ,G=2 ,B=4 THEN

We have 4 red, 2 green, and 4 blue balls. Clearly, we need at least four packages to store 10 balls. One possibility of using exactly four packages looks as follows: RGB, RG, RR, BBB. (I.e., the first package has 1 ball of each color, the second package has a red and a green ball, and so on.)

So in this case answer will be 4.

Answer (score 0):

It can be $\lceil\frac{n}{3}\rceil$ or $\lceil\frac{n}{3}\rceil+1$.

It is clear it can't be less, to prove it can't be more use as many size 3 normal packages and then look at what is left.